# Eclipse RCP P2 Update without changing product version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

I build a Eclipse RCP product using Tycho on a nightly build server. I'd like to allow the product to update itself via a p2 repository, but Eclipse only notices the new version if the product version is changed, although the qualifier of the version does change.

How can I allow to upgrade to the newest nightly build without changing anything manually? I do currently use the Eclipse-integrated update manager, but I could also use the p2 api if it would solve the problem.

If I try to update using the Install New Software dialog without changing the major or minor part of the product version:

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Product" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Product 1.0.0.201502021648 (editor.sdk.feature.group 1.0.0.201502021648)
  Software currently installed: Product 1.0.0 (Product 1.0.0)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Product Main Plugin 1.0.0.201502021648 (Product.editor 1.0.0.201502021648)
    Product Main Plugin 1.0.0.201502011807 (Product.editor 1.0.0.201502011807)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Product 1.0.0 (Product 1.0.0)
    To: editor.sdk.feature.group [1.0.0.201502011807]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: CodeInspect 1.0.0.201502011807 (editor.sdk.feature.group 1.0.0.201502011807)
    To: editor [1.0.0.201502011807]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Product 1.0.0.201502021648 (editor.sdk.feature.group 1.0.0.201502021648)
    To: editor [1.0.0.201502021648]
```

In my product file

```
   <features>
      <feature id="editor.sdk"/>
   </features>
```

The feature.xml of my feature editor.sdk contains the including plugin with version 0.0.0, so it should not be version specific.

After changing the product version it shows a dialog similar to
[image: Choose one of the following alternate solutions]

Comment: The behaviour you are describing really seems weird to me. So just to be sure: The new expanded qualifier is larger (in alphanumeric sort order) than the previous expanded qualifier, right?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, now it seems to work. I have added a Product.p2.inf with the content

```
requires.1.namespace = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
requires.1.name = editor.sdk.feature.group
requires.1.range = [1.0.0, 10.0.0)
```

Now Eclipse updates without a warning and automatically.